# Añadir usuario por default - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy trabajando con laravel y las migraciones.
¿Existe alguna forma de crear un usuario?

Digamos: admin@gmail.com + pass

¿Alguna forma de que esos datos se creen cuando ejecuto `> php artisan migrate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de seeders

```
public function run()
{

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name'  => 'Jhon Smith',
        'email'     => 'admin@gmail.com',
        'password'  => bcrypt('123456'),
    ]);
}
```

luego puedes ejecutar:

`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`    /*Lo que hará es eliminar tus tablas y volverlas a crear */

Si solo quieres ejecutar el seeder:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Mas información en la documentación oficial de Laravel.

[Database: Seeding - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function run()
{

    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name'  => 'user',
        'email'     => 'admin@gmail.com',
        'password'  => bcrypt('pass'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: ¿podrias detallar mejor la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Usa las [migraciones de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) para ello.

Luego con **Eloquent** en la misma migración define tu usuarios por default (Hay tambien puedes usar alguna variable $ENV para modificar la contraseña inicial).

EJ.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFlightsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        $user = new User;

        $user->email = 'myEmail@localhost.com';
        $user->password = '****';

        $user->save();
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto también puede ser incluida en una segunda migración, pro ejemplo usando `php artisan make:migration create_adding_users --create=users`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear un **seeder** para la tabla donde se almacena el usuario. Aquí introduces los usuarios que quieras. Puedes corres el seeder después de las migraciones (cuando las tablas se hayan incluido en la BD)